# Does removing child elements cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript

Does using an event listener to remove child element cause memory leaks?

My HTML file:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child-one">One</div>
    <div class="child-two">Two</div>
    <div class="child-three">Three</div>
    <div class="child-four">Four</div>
    <div class="child-five">Five</div>
  </div>
  <button>Click me!</button>       
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

My javascript file:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const removeChild = () => {
  const containerHtml = document.querySelector('.container');
  while (containerHtml.hasChildNodes()) {
    containerHtml.removeChild(containerHtml.firstChild);
 }
};

btn.addEventListener('click', removeChild);
```

and this is what I record using the Chrome dev tool's performance tool, the js heap keeps going up after I clicked the button to remove all child elements.(I recorded performance for 50 second)

[image]

This is memory leak right? if it is, whats the best way to remove child elements with an event listener?

Comment: I'm not seeing any memory leak in your above code, what part do you think would memory leak?

Comment: Hi but how come the JS Heap keeps rising and it's not coming down, I just did another 5 min performance test and the graph still shows JS Heap keeps going up, thanks

Comment: Javascript uses a garbage collector, the heap will go down when the GC kicks in.  While debugging you can force the GC to kick in by pressing the bin icon.  When you do this you will see the heap go down.

Comment: but how do I know if I have memory leak, what is the graph going to look like when I have a memory leak?

Comment: I believe the official way is to use the memory tab, not the performance tab.  You then take multiple snapshots and then compare.